# google charts and Java

Tags: java, google-visualization

I am very keen to use google charting (visualization api) in my project in which I am making a network monitoring tool. I want to make a client app which will connect server at a port and get statistics about the application. I want to display the statistics using charts.

I tried to read good docs, but its quite confusing, I tried some other websites but no solution. Can anyone provide any good source to learn how to use google charts to display live running data?

Comment: there is no Java wrapper for creating live charts with visualizations. You need to code your own javascript like shown here http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html

Answer (score 4):

Hey , I think charts4j will help you . http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/ .

> charts4j allows you to
>   programmatically generate charts from
>   within your Java code via a simple,
>   intuitive, and lightweight Java API.
>   Moreover, it hides the ugly details of
>   creating the URL parameters that are
>   necessary for communicating with the
>   Google Chart API.

Comment: this only gives ur a URL to to put on ur webpages...thank you for your response..but this is not exactly what i am looking for ..

Comment: yes , once you get the URL , you can use this URL to open an input stream , and then download the graph pictures to your hard-disk.